# Convert SQL query to DAX query used in power bi to find the row with max date for a specific id

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to make a report in power bi, for which I need to find the latest record for all ids.
This is the SQL query that can be run on the table to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM placement 
WHERE dateModified in (
   SELECT max(dateModified) 
   FROM placement 
   GROUP BY ID
   );
```

How can I achieve the same in Power BI using power query or DAX?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FILTER Function like this:

FILTER(placement, dateModified = MAX(placement[dateModified]))

not sure about the syntax, but if you provide some data we can check that is compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a report level filter on a calculated column:

```
IsTopDate = IF(table1[Date] = Calculate(Max(table1[Date]), All(table1)), 1, 0)
```

Then add top date as a report level filter on 1.

OR

Using PowerQuery, do something like so using [Table.Column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/table-column), [List.Max](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/m/list-max) and [Table.SelectRows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query-bi/m/table-selectrows):

[image]

```
#"maxDate" = List.Max(Table.Column(#"Source" as table, "Date" as text) as list  ),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Source", each [Date] = #"maxnum")
```